# Python 3.6 - How to match strings in a for loop?

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm defining a function that counts the number of times XML tags are present in a string, namely `<>` and `</>`. Although I'm able to 'match' the strings, I'm unable to quantify those number of matches to return a numeric `count`. This is my function:

```
def tag_count(the_string):
    count = 0
    for element in the_string:
        if '<>' in the_string:
            count += 1
            return count
        elif '</>' in the_string:
             count += 1
             return count
```

The problem is that for strings that have both `<>` and `</>`, `count` should return the number of times these tags are matched whereas my function is only returning `count` as 1 because of the `elif` condition. I tried inserting `and` in the 3rd line but that gives me an error. How do I sum the number of times these tags are matched?

Comment: move `return count` out of for loop

Comment: Your `return` statement is within your loop. So it returns `1` as soon as it has found the first occurrence. Move `return` to the end, out of the loop to avoid this.

Comment: Note that real XML tags looks like `<x>...</x>` or `<x/>`, and not `<>` or `</>`. You need a different way of matching to catch them. Also, you count open-close tags as two tags. A reasonable implementation would likely also check that open and close tags match each other; this would require a stack. For a practical purpose I'd take a real XML parser (included in Python) and count non-text nodes in the tree recursively.

Comment: Many thanks for all the responses!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You return from the function every time you encounter a tag, that's why it's always 1. You can also use the `str.count()` method:

```
def tag_count(source):
    return source.count('<>') + source.count('</>')
```

Example usage:

```
>>> tag_count('<> <> </> <> <>')
5
```

Comment: This is elegance.

Comment: What if the string was something like `['<String>', 'Foo!', '</string>]`. Then how would the universal matching work?

Comment: If you have a real XML document with syntax like `<tag attr="value"><nested /></tag>`, your only sane option would be using an actual XML parser (you can find some in modules `xml` or `ltree`). If your data is a subset of XML (where does the splitting come from, by the way?), there might be a simpler method, but there's no way to tell without knowing precisely what you're dealing with.

Comment: For example I'm having a simple list of strings `list = ['<Hello>', 'World!', '</This>', '<is>', '</Python>']` and would like to sum up the number of starting and ending tags here.

Comment: In a simple case like this you might use list comprehension to filter out those that don't start with an opening bracket or don't end with a closing one: `len([item for item in items if item.startswith('<') and item.endswith('>')])`